# Get Key-Value pairs in SimpleFormController from HTML table generated by jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a jsp page with an HTML table. The table has two colums key-value.
The value is an `input` field and can be changed by the user.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Property1</td>
        <td><input value="Value1"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Property2</td>
        <td><input value="Value2"/></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- etc... -->
</table>
```

When submitting the form the `onSubmit` of the `SimpleFormController` is triggered. 
Here I want to to retrieve the key-value pairs. Preferably in a Map.

I know only how to select parameters from the request through the `name` attribute using `getParameter()`. I don't see how I can map my keys to the corresponding values by using the `name` attribute.

```
@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
        throws Exception {
    //iterate over key-value pairs
}
```

FYI: the table is dynamically generated so retrieveing with ID's is not an option because I don't know how many key-value pairs there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ServletRequest#getParameterMap()` to retrieve a map containing parameter names as keys and parameter values as map values. Javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29)